# I have tried to connect my Raspberry Pi using the HDMI lead, but it says no signal on the monitor and on the tv

Tags: hdmi, display

I can't get my Raspberry Pi to connect via HDMI to either a TV or a monitor. It will connect using AV leads. I have searched various forums, but the advice is always rather technical and doesn't seem to fit with what I see on screen. Any ideas?

Comment: What is it you see on screen? It will be most helpful if you describe in detail what you've experienced so far.

Comment: If I hook up via av I get raspberry pi desktop but if I switch to hdmi i get a no signal message

Comment: what distro are you using?

Comment: Is HDMI connected and TV/monitor turned on at boot time?  If not, it'll switch to the analog cable.

Comment: yes the tv/monitor are switched on. not sure what a distro is??

Comment: "distro" is jargon for [(Linux) distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution).

Comment: One more thing to try would be having the TV turned off, then connecting, then turning on the Pi - the Pi normally sends a "wakeup" signal via CEC - if the TV turns on (and possibly switches inputs to the Pi), then it would indicate something working (just not the video)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to set

```
    hdmi_force_hotplug=1
```

in the `/boot/config.txt` on the sdcard?

If this is not working you can also try

```
    hdmi_safe=1
```

Comment: I'm having this problem as well. I added/uncommented that line in config.txt on the boot partition which didn't work. Is it supposed to go in the boot folder of the main partition instead?

Comment: @Trengot, the file is supposed to be in the `/boot` folder - so that's fine. I had a troublesome RPi (Kernelpanic...) that did not show up on HDMI until setting `hdmi_safe=1`. If it is not working for you, well, maybe something else is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Push the HDMI connector in all the way (it fixed the problem for me).

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. Could you please edit it to make it sound like an answer? Obviously it is a possible error.